# How to retrieve more than one record in the database with the method find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Can you help me with this problem?. I have a model called Person that has two fields called name and surname
I have two records what are same but when called a Person.find_by(name:'fernando') show me an only record, but in the database there are two records same

```
<Person id: 1, name: "fernando", surname: "barroso", created_at: "2014-07-09 15:15:47", updated_at: "2014-07-09 15:15:47">
<Person id: 4, name: "fernando", surname: "barroso", created_at: "2014-07-09 15:34:01", updated_at: "2014-07-09 15:34:01">
```

Would this have to return a collection of objects?

```
2.0.0-p481 :033 > Person.all
  Person Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Person id: 1, name: "fernando", surname: "barroso", created_at: "2014-07-09 15:15:47", updated_at: "2014-07-09 15:15:47">, #<Person id: 2, name: "juan", surname: "perez", created_at: "2014-07-09 15:19:39", updated_at: "2014-07-09 15:19:39">, #<Person id: 3, name: "juan", surname: "pepe", created_at: "2014-07-09 15:23:06", updated_at: "2014-07-09 15:23:06">, #<Person id: 4, name: "fernando", surname: "barroso", created_at: "2014-07-09 15:34:01", updated_at: "2014-07-09 15:34:01">]> 
2.0.0-p481 :034 > user= Person.find_by(name:'fernando')
  Person Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."name" = 'fernando' LIMIT 1
 => #<Person id: 1, name: "fernando", surname: "barroso", created_at: "2014-07-09 15:15:47", updated_at: "2014-07-09 15:15:47">
```

Comment: `find_by` always returns a single record.You want `find_all_by` or `where`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to retrieve more than one record with...method `find_by`

You don't. The express purpose of [that method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by) is to find the **first** record matching the given criteria.

> Model.find_by finds the first record matching some conditions. For example:
>
> ```
> Client.find_by first_name: 'Lifo'
> ```
>
> ... is equivalent to writing:
>
> ```
> Client.where(first_name: 'Lifo').take
> ```

If you want to retrieve more than one record, use `where`:

```
Person.where(name: 'fernando')
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Rails will only return the first item if you use `find_by`. You need to use `where` if you really want to get all the items

`Person.where(name: 'fernando')`

Actually, `find_by` is the shortcut for `where(conditions).first`

Comment: `.first` is wrong; it's a shortcut for `where(conditions).take`.